# Android view.setBackgroundColor() from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-view

I have implemented a gameloop to work on `SurfaceView`, it works perfectly but when scaling down or moving canvas it renders snapshots of scaling behind the canvas which is annoying.

So I want to clear my view background after `onDraw()` calls. I tried using `view.setBackgroundColor()` from the gameloop or inside `onDraw()` but android claims that I can use it from another thread.

Is there any equivalent method to do so?

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread
{
    private MapView view;
    private boolean running = false;
    static final long FPS = 30;

    public GameLoopThread(MapView view)
    {   this.view = view;    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run)
    {   running = run;    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (running)
        {
                Canvas c = null;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try
                {
                    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (view.getHolder())
                    {   
                        view.onDraw(c);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // fails on this
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (c != null)
                        view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
                sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                try
                {
                    if (sleepTime > 0) sleep(sleepTime);
                    else sleep(10);
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Update

I don't want to use view.setBackgroundColor() instead I want to use something equivalent to draw behin the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is better to use the Handler, because **GameLoopThread** has no **Context**

```
android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update here
            }
        });
```

make **private MapView view**; to **final**

Answer (score 2):

You can't update **UI** from a separate thread instead you can use `runOnUiThread`

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, I look for another solution

Comment: @AhmadDwaik'Warlock' I don't see that you are using `runOnUiThread` in your code

Comment: @AhmadDwaik'Warlock' where are you declaring/calling `GameLoopThread` ?

Comment: Well, I remember why I haven't use my game loop on main thread. because it runs like a 30 fps makes the device hang. I went to only update background on seperate thread that runs on ui. which i guess it will hang too

Comment: nope if you update the background on UiThread the device will not hang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67534/discussion-between-abdellah-and-ahmad-dwaik-warlock).

Answer (score 2):

You can only "Change" views from the UIThread. So a possible solution would be passing your `Activity-Context` and use

`activityContext.runOnUiThread`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can update UI thread from `handlers`, `asynctasks`, or `runOnUIThread` method. You cannot do that from a normal thread

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for posting answers.

I have found my need which in its turn works as `setBackgroundColor()`

It's as simple as calling `drawColor()`

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); // fill the whole canvas with white
    // rest of drawing
}
```